# Bug in angular.js ng-click listener or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems like this code will, forever after I've clicked my button once, constantly reset winnerName and loserName to ''. Even if I set them to something else, they instantly gets reseted. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addGame(winnerName, loserName); winnerName = ''; loserName = '';" >Add game</button>
```

If I move the string reseting to the addGame()-function, everything works as usual.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? hard to comprehend

Comment: Best to move them into the function, if you need to initialize, use `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a plunker to test this syntax and everything seems to work well (see: http://plnkr.co/edit/8ixYchcW6AHdCkYd10fg?p=preview). The key test is clicking on the "Everything Off" button which is defined as follows:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="textOff(); showBold = false; showRed = false;" value="EVERYTHING OFF" />
```

As you can see the ng-click here calls a function and also sets two variables which is the same syntax that you were using. The textOff function looks like:

```
$scope.textOff = function (){
  $scope.displayText = "";
};
```

Even after that, though, when you click on the other toggle buttons the text and styles still toggle normally. I'm guessing that something else is going on here. Probably something else is resetting the values constantly or they aren't getting set again the way you expect.

Hope this helps some!